# How to define class constructor outside class in another file?

Tags: c++

So, I've got a class Car:

**car.h**

```
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "car.cpp"

// Car class with its attributes
class Car {
  public:
    std::string brand;   
    std::string model;
    int year;

    // Constructor
    Car(int year, std::string model, std::string brand);
};

#endif
```

and I wanted to make a class constructor definition outside the class in another .cpp file:

**car.cpp**

```
#include <string.h>

Car::Car(int year, std::string model, std::string brand)
{
  this->brand = brand;
  this->model = model;
  this->year = year;
}
```

I tried to compile, but this error has occurred:

`car.cpp:3:1: error: ‘Car’ does not name a type`

Why it happened and how to fix it?

**My main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "car.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
  // Create an object of Car
  Car carObj1 = Car(1992, "model X", "Brand1");

  // Create another object of Car
  Car carObj2 = Car(2003, "model Y", "Brand2");

  // Print attribute values
  cout << carObj1.brand << " " << carObj1.model << " " << carObj1.year << "\n";
  cout << carObj2.brand << " " << carObj2.model << " " << carObj2.year << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [OT]: `#include <string.h>` -> `#include <string>`

Comment: `car.cpp` needs to `#include "car.h"` so the compiler has visibility of the definition of `Car` before defining its constructor.    It is not possible to define (aka implement) any member function of a class if the compiler does not have visibility of the class definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got the includes the wrong way round. car.cpp should `#include "car.h"` not the other way around.

Also the correct header file for `std::string` is `<string>` not `<string.h>`

Also member initialisation is better done with initialiser lists not assignment

```
Car::Car(int year, std::string model, std::string brand) :
    brand(brand), model(model), year(year)
{
}
```

Comment: also, no need for `car.cpp` in `car.h`

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> #include "car.cpp"
> ```

This is wrong. Never include source files.

> ```
> ‘Car’ does not name a type
> ```
>
> Why it happened

car.cpp attempts to use the class `Car` which has not been defined.

> how to fix it?

Add `#include "car.h"` into car.cpp to define `Car` before its use. Then remove `#include "car.cpp"` from car.h to avoid recursive inclusion that would prevent correct order of inclusion.

Comment: Okay, thank you, now it worked. I should ask StackOverflow immediately because I was dealing with this error for 1 hour. But in the end, I've learned something.